# Split list of objects by object attribute

Tags: python-3.x, list, collections, split

I am unable to figure out how to split a list of objects by object value.
For example:

```
class car:
    cid=0
    type="undef"

    def  __init__(self, cid,type):
        self.cid=cid
        self.type=type

    def show(self):
        print("car id : "+str(self.cid)+" car type : "+self.type)

car_list=[]
car_list.append(car(34,"Suv"))
car_list.append(car(47,"Suv"))
car_list.append(car(48,"Suv"))
car_list.append(car(42,"hb"))
car_list.append(car(40,"hb"))
car_list.append(car(37,"sed"))
car_list.append(car(77,"sed"))
car_list.append(car(22,"sed"))
```

I want to split `car_list` into a list of cars of each type. Then print the type of car before the list.
Expected output:

```
SUV
==========================
car id : 34 car type : Suv
car id : 47 car type : Suv
car id : 47 car type : Suv
HB
==========================
car id : 47 car type : hb
car id : 47 car type : hb
SED
==========================
car id : 47 car type : sed
car id : 47 car type : sed
car id : 47 car type : sed
```

Answer (score 0):

U can make a list of the type first like `types = ['SUV', 'HB', 'SED']` or search the type from the list with looping:

```
types = []
for car in car_list:
    if not car.type in types:
        types.append(car.type)
```

Last, loop again to get the same type:

```
for type in types:
    print(type.upper())
    for car in car_list:
        if car.type.lower() == type.lower():
            car.show()
```

Comment: all possible type of cars is not known beforehand.

Comment: That i said 'search the type from the list with looping'. Can handle if type of cars in not known

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out :

```html
from collections import groupby 
grouped_car_list= groupby(car_list, key = lambda car : car.type)

for  type , cars in grouped_car_list:
    print(type)
    print("=============================")
    for car in cars:
        car.show()
```